# tell jquery mobile / phonegap app to wait until content is loaded

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, jquery-mobile, phonegap

I've got a phonegap app using jquery, jquery mobile, js, css & html.

I use listview to show and filter a lot of LI's. When the lists are text only they work great. But when (as I want) the LI's are solely populated with images - a random number of them fail to load, leaving just some blank LI's.

(When testing on my pc in Chrome it works fine. It only fails once ut's phonegap'd and running on a phone as an app).

If I slow the index page by adding a few hundred lines of useless code - then the images all display.

So I think the problem is that the page loads and finalises before the images have all loaded.

Is there any way to tell the app not to load until all the images are ready?

edit: The code I'm using:

```
<div data-role="content">
       <ul data-role="listview" data-icon="false" data-filter="true" data-filter-placeholder="Search all cards..." data-inset="true">

    <li data-role="list-divider">List of things</li>
    <li data-filtertext="various:different:keywords"><div><img src="img/01046.jpg" class="cardimg"></div></li>
    <li data-filtertext="various:different:keywords"><div><img src="img/01047.jpg" class="cardimg"></div></li>
    <li data-filtertext="various:different:keywords"><div><img src="img/01048.jpg" class="cardimg"></div></li>
...
```

and so on. There are a lot of images, and the number is only going to get bigger over time.

Comment: Have you considered using [window.onload()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/GlobalEventHandlers/onload)? This method waits for images to load as well.

Comment: I don't know my way around jquery or js very well yet, I've spent a heap of time now looking into and trying different window.onload() variations with no luck. I'm just not sure what function I should be triggering with it? Should I be looking at something that'll delay page display until the images are loaded, or trigger a refresh on all listviews? or.. what should I be using it to trigger?

Answer (score 0):

You should add the `<li>` containing the image to your `<ul>` when each of the image is loaded. Inside the image callback `img.onload` add the `<li>` and refresh your JQM Filterable Listview.

Here is an example:

```js
var imagesList = [
  {searchWords: "Lewis HAMILTON", src: "https://via.placeholder.com/2323x2323"},
  {searchWords: "Sebastian VETTEL", src: "https://via.placeholder.com/1212x1212"},
  {searchWords: "Kimi RAIKKONEN", src: "https://via.placeholder.com/2333x2333"},
  {searchWords: "Felipe MASSA", src: "https://via.placeholder.com/2000x2000"},
  {searchWords: "Valtteri BOTTAS", src: "https://via.placeholder.com/1111x1111"},
  {searchWords: "Daniel RICCIARDO", src: "https://via.placeholder.com/666x666"},
  {searchWords: "Nicolas HULKENBERG", src: "https://via.placeholder.com/2222x2222"}
], remaining;

function addToList() {
  remaining--;
  var head = $("#page-images-list .ui-header h1");
  var msg = (remaining === 0) ? "All images loaded." : "Remaining: " + remaining;
  $(head).html(msg);
  var html = '<li data-filtertext="'+this.searchWords+'">';
  html += '<a href="#">';
  html += '<img src="'+this.src+'">';
  html += '<h2>'+this.searchWords+'</h2>';
  html += '<p>'+this.src+'</p></a>';
  html += '</li>';
  $("#listview-images").append(html);
  //$("#listview-images").listview("refresh");
  $("#listview-images").filterable("refresh");
}

function loadImages(dest, list) {
  $(dest).empty();
  remaining = list.length;
  $.each(list, function(index, item) {
    var img = new Image();
    img.searchWords = item.searchWords;
    img.onload = addToList;
    setTimeout(function() {
      img.src = item.src;
    }, 0);
  });
}
$(document).on("vclick", "#btn-reload", function(e) {
  loadImages("#listview-images", imagesList);
});

$(document).on("pagecontainershow", function(e, ui) {
  if (typeof ui.toPage == "object") {
    switch (ui.toPage.prop("id")) {
      case "page-images-list":
        loadImages("#listview-images", imagesList);
        break;
    }
  }
});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, user-scalable=no">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.4.5/jquery.mobile-1.4.5.css">
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.2.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.4.5/jquery.mobile-1.4.5.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
  <div id="page-images-list" data-role="page">
    <div data-role="header" data-position="fixed">
    <a href="#" id="btn-reload" class="ui-btn-left ui-btn ui-btn-inline ui-mini ui-corner-all ui-btn-icon-left ui-icon-refresh">Reload</a>
      <h1>Images callback</h1>
    </div>
    <div role="main" class="ui-content">
      <ul data-role="listview" data-inset="true" data-filter="true" id="listview-images">
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

**Additional note:**

if you are using a `list divider` to group your list content, please note that the image arrival sequence will be not guaranteed to be in the same order as it has been defined in the images list array. This depends from how big each image is and from network traffic. So, if you additionally need to group your list items in a certain way, you will need some additional code to sort again your list elements when each images is loaded. If all images have been already downloaded and are cached by the browser, then the array order will be (probably) maintained.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I don't know my way around jquery or js enough yet to know in what context to use img.onload - I'm researching it now, but edited some of my code into the original question hoping for a little more guidance! :)